WP behind nginx reverse proxy, home page stuck in redirect loop
I have a home page stuck in a 301 redirect loop.
I have two servers. ServerA and ServerB.
serverA:
domain-a.com
using nginx reverse proxy
ServerB:
domain-b.com
using nginx
domain-a.com proxy domain-b.com
Symptoms

The site is configured to display a static page. If I change it to display the most recent posts, they display correctly.

It does not matter which static page I have set as the home page, none of them render correctly as the home page.

The static pages render just fine when I view them directly (eg, https://domain-a.com/home-page/)

Doesn't matter which theme is active, the homepage behaves the same way.


What I've Tried

Regenerating permalinks

Disabling all plugins


I use domain-a.com to access the Wordpress site. If I change the WP display the most recent posts, they display correctly.
If I change the permalinks as "Plain", https://www.domain-a.com/?p=123, then the homepage working well, But I need "post name" type URL.
Nginx reverse proxy configuration:
# ServerA Nginx
#PROXY-START/

location ^~ /
{
    proxy_pass https://domain-b.com;
    proxy_set_header Host domain-b.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    # proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
    port_in_redirect off;
    
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    #Set Nginx Cache


    if ( $uri ~* "\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|woff|woff2)$" )
    {
        expires 1m;
    }
    proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie Cache-Control expires;
    proxy_cache cache_one;
    proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 304 301 302 1m;
}

    location @handle_redirects {
        set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
    }
#PROXY-END/

//ServerB, wp-config.php

define('WP_HOME','https://domain-a.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://domain-a.com');

